# Firestore: startAt in geohash query for infinite scrolll in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app and i want to get nearest posts from users in a user feed. So an user can read all nearby posts in his location. So i'm using this code:

```
let query =  dbRef
            .orderBy('location.geohash')
            .where("location.geohash", ">=", range.lower)
            .where("location.geohash", "<=", range.upper)
            .limit(9)
```

The problem is when i want to add ".startAt(somefield)." is impossible to retrieve more  data because geohashes aren't unique. And actually i have the same problem if i want to order this fetch with .orderBy(timestamp) (it doesn't work)

So my question is. There is actually a way to do this. Or maybe i have to opt move on to a relational data base like mysql?

Comment: All queries implicitly end with an `orderBy` call on document ID. If you pass a `DocumentSnapshot` to `startAt()` it has all information needed to find the starting document, even when the `location.geohash` value isn't unique.

Comment: Hi, i appreciate your answer, i watched your video on youtube about this. Okay, but when i add startAt("geohashhere") i only get one result and then crashes. Check this image. please https://prnt.sc/u1r8p8. This doesn't happen when i only uses dbRef.orderBy("timestamp").limit(9).startAt(" a date here "). Here works good

Comment: As said: you'll need to pass the `DocumentSnapshot`, or at the very least the geohash and document ID so that the ID can be used to disambiguate.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what i understand about you say is to do this:
https://i.imgur.com/0ueDBLT.png
But i got duplicated data

Comment: Ok i solved with Async function to wait for the response before make de get query. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know how i solved it. I did this way (thanks to Frank van Puffelen indications)

I created a newData variable for saving documentSnapshot and then i made a async get query to firebase with the last document ID to get the snapshot.

```
let newData

        if(docId)  {
            await dbRef.doc(docId).get().then(documentSnapshot => {
                if (documentSnapshot) {
                    newData = documentSnapshot
                }
              });
        }
```

Then if newData isn't null i add startAfter with newData variable to the query

```
let query =  dbRef
                .where("location.geohash", ">=", range.lower)
                .where("location.geohash", "<=", range.upper)
                .orderBy('location.geohash')
                
                if(newData) {
                    query = query.startAfter(newData)
                }
                
            query = query.limit(9)
           
            query.get()
            .then(res => {
                    if (res) { 
                        res.docs.map(doc => { return doc.data() }) 
                    }
            })
```